# What font is used in the SO error page?

Tags: discussion, fonts

This font is quite easy on my eyes...

[image: SO Error Image]

Which is it?

Comment: I believe this is some custom font, not one of the ordinary "built in" fonts that come with Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments on the [question about the joke](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code) in the 404 page indicates that someone has already done the hard work by posting it on [What the Font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/295724/), MyFont's font identification forum/service:

> Just to follow up, the font is **Pragmata**: http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fsd/pragmata/tt – [mattalexx](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148227/mattalexx) Jul 21 at 21:44

[image]